# Vue.js Sample Project msg not updating

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I installed Vue.js and ran `vue create hello-world`. I then went into `App.vue` and updated the message as follows:

```
<template>
 <div id="app">
 <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
 <HelloWorld msg="Hello World!"/>
 </div>
</template>
```

I ran `npm run serve` and the original message of "Welcome to Your Vue.js App" still displays.

What am I missing? This seems way too basic not to work. If I change the code to something invalid, it errors out, so I know the file is being changed, and the server is updating.

Comment: That's really strange, I just did what you described, `vue create hello-world` with default setup, and then `npm run serve`, and the page reloads instantly with the new text when I change `msg=""`. You followed the right steps, and your frustration is justified! Maybe try clearing your browser cache?

Comment: @zcoop98 Thank you. I tried in another browser and works perfectly. Which makes no sense is that it will show the error message, but not show the updated text?

Reset cache for localhost and now it works in both browsers. *throws hands in air*

Comment: This was the problem I was running into with Safari and Vue.js

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1132#issuecomment-409916879